# Korge gradle setup for JVM target

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea, korge

I want to try the Korge libs on the JVM.
I used the Korge IntelliJ plugin to create a new project.
My build.gradle.kts looks like this :

```kotlin
import com.soywiz.korge.gradle.*

buildscript {
  val korgePluginVersion: String by project

  repositories {
      mavenLocal()
      mavenCentral()
      google()
      maven { url = uri("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/") }
  }
  dependencies {
      classpath("com.soywiz.korlibs.korge.plugins:korge-gradle-plugin:$korgePluginVersion")
  }
}

apply<KorgeGradlePlugin>()

korge {
  id = "amap3.amap3"
  targetJvm()
}
```

I've copied the commonMain code into the jvmMain folder and running the project with the runJvm command.
I've looked into the examples on the korge doc and github, but i can't manage to solve the following silly question :
If I have a java dependency from maven, let's say

```kotlin
implementation("com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.0")
```

where do I put it in this file ?

Thank you very much for your attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find the answer in the documentation either, but after going through the Gradle plugin source files, it appears that they are using the `addDependency` function in the `korge {}` block. In your case it would look something like this:

```kotlin
korge {
  id = "amap3.amap3"
  targetJvm()

  addDependency("jvmMainImplementation", "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.0")
}
```